# variable changing value inside for... loop

Tags: python, variables, scope

I have this piece of code:

```
if (currstates and useravailable(currstates)):
    thisstates = list(currstates)
    for token in unserved:

        mode, timestamp = modality(token, thisstates)

        to_write = str(timestamp)+' '+str(token[1])+' '+str(token[2])+' '+mode+'\n'
        output.write(to_write)
        unserved.remove(token)
```

where i call the function:

```
def modality(token, herestate):
    #print(herestate)
    if (token[3] == 'high'):
        timest = token[0]
    else:
        timest = herestate[0]
    modal = 'auditory'
    if herestate[2] == 'phone':
        modal = 'visual'
    elif (herestate[3] == 'silent' or herestate[4]=='quiet'):
        modal = 'tactile'
    #print(timest)
    return (modal,timest)
```

I dont understand why the

```
thisstates
```

variable changes values between the two iterations over

```
unserved
```

I am not able to understand why this is happening. My code has other components too, so I can explain if you need any details. Thanks.

Comment: modifying the list while you are looping over it can cause unexpected results.

Comment: I dont see any modification of the list though... can you point out if there is?

Comment: `unserved.remove(token)`.

Comment: I'm just pointing out that you are modifying `unserved` while looping over it. I'm not sure why `thisstates` is changing. Is the for loop being executed multiple times? If so check if `currstates` is changing

Comment: okay. that was stupid! :D i think i need some rest from coding too much :p

Comment: I am not sure why it works after removing the 'unserved.remove(token)' part. it is still in the loop, but somehow the values of thisstates and currstates both are changed. this should not be the case.